# Why does my browser keep crashing when I run this Javascript code?

Tags: javascript, loops, crash, infinite-loop

This is my code:

```
for (var i=1;1<=10;i++) {
    console.log(i);
}

var count = 10;
while (count>0) {
    console.log(count);
    count--;
}
do {
    console.log("1 loop");
} while (count === 1000);
```

The only thing I could think of is an infinite loop, but there doesn't seem to be one to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first line of your code has a `1` instead of an `i`

```
for (var i=1;1<=10;i++) {
```

Comment: Thanks! That was pretty dumb of me ;)